# open source semantic web project

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

I am looking for an open source semantic web project, I know there are Jena and Sesame but I'm looking for another open source semantic web project.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a variety of tools.  If you can elaborate on your target language and platform plus what you want to do with the project then people can give you a better answer

Comment: You can also check [DBPedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/join). DBpedia basically extracts triples from Wikipedia. It is one of the most popular resources in semantic web community.
They have several initiatives that could be of interest to you.

Answer (score 7):

What sort of Semantic Web project?

**APIs**

- [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) - My C# .Net API
- [rdflib](http://www.rdflib.net) - Python API
- [ARC2](http://arc.semsol.org) - PHP API

And there is pretty much one/more API for any language you fancy so if you can elaborate on the language desired I can make an appropriate recommendation

**Triple Stores**

- [4store](http://4store.org) - A C Linux based clusterable triple store
- [Virtuoso](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtuoso/) - Commercial Triple Store (written in C++) from OpenLink Software which has a cut down open source version - runs on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X afaik
- [AllegroGraph](http://www.franz.com/agraph/allegrograph/) - Commercial Triple Store (written in LISP) from Franz Inc which has a limited (50 million Triples) free to use version

Again there are lots of projects for lots of platforms - elaborate on your target environment to get a better answer

**Other Tools**

Also there are a variety of GUI tools for things like editing, ontology design etc

Plus you can get CMSs with Semantic Web tech built in such as [Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/) and [Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/)

Comment: 4store is written in C - not C++ ;-) - and also run in Mac and Unix distributions not just Linux. Good list of tools though +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the only bits  missing from RobV's answer are some of the reasoning tools like:

1. [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/)
2. [Hermit](http://hermit-reasoner.com/)

... some other triple stores:

1. [Mulgara](http://www.mulgara.org/)
2. [Talis Platform](http://www.talis.com/platform/) this is a service that you can use if you use Open Data and less than XX million triples. I don't remember exactly how many.
3. [BigData](http://www.systap.com/bigdata.htm)

... and of course [Redland libraries](http://librdf.org/), one of my favourite set of tools with some very useful command line utilities.

Answer (score 2):

You might even look at [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) - with the release of version 7, Drupal now supports RDFa and any extension of semantic capabilities will surely be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of them actually. For example [Big Data](http://www.systap.com/bigdata.htm). You can find more [here](http://semanticweb.org/wiki/Tools).

Answer (score 0):

Well, already mentioned some I know.

You can also check:

- [CubicWeb](http://www.cubicweb.org/): Python Framework
- [Pellet](http://www.cubicweb.org/): OWL DL Reasoner based in Java. Dual licensing, not sure if OpenSource
- [FaCT++](http://owl.man.ac.uk/factplusplus/): OWL DL Reasoner based
- [SPARQLWrapper](http://sparql-wrapper.sourceforge.net/): if you want to query RDF endpoints from Python
- [RedLand](http://librdf.org/): RDF API based in C with Bindings for Python, Ruby and Perl (librdf in Python)